# Creating a Windows 10 Install USB when FAT32 has 4GB max file size

Tags: bootcamp, windows, usb

So I am attempting to create a Windows 10 install USB on my MBP running macOS 10.14 Mojave. To create a bootable USB it needs to be formatted into FAT32, not exFAT. The issue is that when copying the `.iso` to the USB it fails because the file `sources/install.wim` is 4.4GB. I can't format as exFAT because I cannot boot from that format and I cannot use FAT32 because of the 4.4GB file. I used the command `cp -rpv /Volumes/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9/* /Volumes/WINDOWS10/` after Boot Camp Assistant failed to create the  USB with a "Drive too small" error, even though it was a 16GB drive. When I wasn't paying attention, the `cp` completed and the installer booted, but failed with a `missing: sources/install.wim` error because the file can't be copied.

Is there any solution to this problem, or should I just burn a DVD with the installer on it?

**EDIT:** I forgot to specify that I was creating a USB for a PC, not a Mac. The Mac was just being used to create an install USB.

Heres the file:
[image: 4.4gb file]

Comment: What year is your Mac? I ask because you refer to the use of a optical drive.

Comment: It is a 2012 MBP with an optical drive, but the receiving pc does not, which would require an external drive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found that after upgrading to High Sierra, my 2013 iMac could boot the Windows 10 installer from a ExFAT formatted USB flash drive.

Here are three potential ways to create the USB installer. I am sure there are may other ways.

### Answer #1

Mac computers running High Sierra or Mojave may be able to boot from USB flash drives that are ExFAT formatted. *So, Apple could fix this problem by changing to Boot Camp Assistant to format the USB flash drive as ExFAT instead of FAT32.* For now, you can use the following steps to create a USB Windows 10 flash drive installer.

1. Download the Windows 10 October 2018 Update ISO file from the Microsoft website [Download Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO).
2. Use the Boot Camp Assistant application to download the Windows Support Software. Look for `Download the Windows Support Software` under `Action` on the Menu Bar. After the download finishes, the Window Support Software folder should appear as shown below.

   [image: a2]
3. Use the Disk Utility application to erase a 16 GB or larger USB flash drive. Choose Name, Format and Scheme as shown in the image below..

   [image: d1]
4. Use the Finder application to mount the ISO file. The name of the ISO file, I downloaded, was `Win10_1809Oct_English_x64.iso`. The volume name, when mounted, was `CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9`. Your names may be different.
5. Use the Finder application to copy the contents of the ISO file to the USB flash drive. When finished, the root folder of the USB flash drive should appear as shown below.

   [image: a1]
6. Use the Finder application to copy the Window Support Software to the USB flash drive. When finished, the root folder of the USB flash drive should appear as shown below.

   [image: a3]

The USB flash drive installer can now be used to install Windows on your Mac. If wish to use the flash drive to install Windows 10 on a different Mac, then you should replace the Windows Support Software files with ones downloaded on that Mac.

### Answer #2

> This answer was suggested (in a now deleted comment) by [Solar Mike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/237687/solar-mike). I will remove the answer, if he posts a similar answer.

Use a machine running Windows to create the USB flash drive installer. At this point the flash drive does not contain the Windows Support Software provided by Apple. To add this software, follow steps 2 and 6 of Answer #1.

When using the Windows operating system, you can download the application `MediaCreationTool1809.exe`. This allows the creation of either a USB flash drive installer or the download of an ISO file. *Mac users do not download an application. Instead, Mac users can only download the ISO file.* The MediaCreationTool1809 creates a FAT32 formatted USB installer. So there must be a difference between the files downloaded for the USB installer and the files downloaded in the ISO. I do not know how many of the files are different. However, I do know the largest file is different. This file contains all the Window 10 images. The MediaCreationTool1809 application creates the file `install.esd` which is 3.45 GB in size. This is nowhere near the 4 GB limit for files stored on FAT32 formatted volumes. Unfortunately, the ISO substitutes the file `install.wim` which is 4.4 GB in size. This is well over the 4 GB limit.

> Either `.esd` files are more efficient in storage than `.wim` files or the `install.esd` file has less images than the `install.wim` file.

### Answer #3

Download the Windows 10 April 2018 Update ISO file from the Microsoft website [Download Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). This ISO file is compatible with the Boot Camp Assistant. After using the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 10, you should goto the Microsoft website [Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to upgrade to the Windows 10 October 2018 Update. **Note: This last link will only work when booted to Windows. If booted to macOS, then you redirect to [Download Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)**

Comment: Great answer, but I did forget to specify that I was creating the USB on a mac, but it was to setup a windows PC. I'll edit my question but you have a lot of useful information, which did solve my problem. I'll just use a windows machine to make the USB.

Comment: @Minebomber: Answer #3 would still work, but you would probably want to delete the files and folders shown in step 2 of answer #1 from the USB flash drive.

Comment: @Minebomber: Another possible solution would be to install VirtualBox on the Mac. VirtualBox is a free product. Create a virtual Windows 10 machine, then use Answer #2 to create the flash drive. You will **not** need a product key to install Windows 10 in a virtual machine on a trial basis.

Comment: Answer 3 is no longer valid as the only iso available is Win10_2004, which suffers from the 4.4GB install.wim issue.

Comment: @KellyBang: There is a [website](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php) where older Microsoft software can be downloaded. I suppose a version 1803 ESD file of Windows 10 could be downloaded and converted to a ISO using the procedure from this other [website](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-iso-file-using-installesd-image). I have not verified if this would work. This might make a good question for you to ask.

Answer (score 33):

The only way I was able to successfully overcome this problem was following [this person's guide](https://alexlubbock.com/bootable-windows-usb-on-mac):

> The final problem is that the `install.wim` file is too big to copy across to the FAT32-formatted USB stick (you can try, but will be met with an error). On Windows, [Microsoft's official solution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/install-windows-from-a-usb-flash-drive) is to split the file using a special tool designed for these `.wim` files. Fortunately, there's also a free alternative called [wimlib](https://wimlib.net/) which works on Mac (and Linux).

With wimlib installed, available via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (`brew install wimlib`), you can easily perform the file splitting of `install.wim` that the Windows 10 ISO will automatically pickup and understand with no extra fuss.

```bsh
wimlib-imagex split /Volumes/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9/sources/install.wim /Volumes/WINDOWS10/sources/install.swm 4000
```

Comment: This does not work as expected. And it was clear to me, as I read it. Tried it anyway. Windows installer could not find `install.wim`.

Comment: should it be `/Volumes/WINDOWS10/sources/install.swm` and not `/Volumes/WINDOWS10/sources/install.wim`?

Comment: has to be swm (see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/install-windows-from-a-usb-flash-drive and https://alexlubbock.com/bootable-windows-usb-on-mac)

Comment: Getting an ``ERROR: Exiting with error code 47: Failed to open a file.`` with this command. Also tried with ``/Volumes/WIN10/sources/install.swm``

Comment: Was skeptical from all these comments, but it worked great for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Zeesy I also got the error. In my case, my USB storage had not enough space. So, i first had to delete `install.wim` which was failed to copy because when i failed to copy a file, it was partially copied rather than deleted. Then, i tried the answer above again. It works!

Answer (score 2):

Do the following on a PC:

- Create a folder called "wim" on the root of your C drive (so C:\wim).  Inside that folder, create another folder called "split."  Of course you can create different names, but for the sake of the following command, we are going with this.  Now copy your large wim file to C:\wim.
- Type the following command, which will split your wim file into smaller sizes, which will fit perfectly on a FAT32 USB stick:

  dism /split-image /ImageFile:C:\wim\install.wim /SWMFile:C:\wim\split\install.swm /FileSize:2000
- Now delete the wim file off of your USB stick (in the sources folder) and replace it with the several .swm files in the C:\wim\split folder.  Because we said filesize=2000, it will split the wim file into approx 2GB files.  Had we said 1000, it would be approx 1GB files.
- Now you don't have to mess around with alternate file systems.  Use the media creation tool from Microsoft to build your USB stick, then delete the .esd file out of the "sources" folder on the USB stick, then put these split install.swm files in its place.  As long as they are named "install.swm, install2.swm, etc," Windows will treat them like a standard wim file and install Windows normally.

Comment: Creating a virtual machine to use as the PC is also an option for those who don't have a PC around to do this on

Answer (score 2):

https://twocanoes.com/using-larger-windows-10-isos-with-boot-camp-assistant/
splits 4+ GB install.wim to smaller parts automatically

Answer (score 1):

### 2021 update

.iso files under 4GB have been removed from most of the posted online sources, including the [official Windows download site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). As of February 2021, there's only one ISO version available. I had the best luck downloading a free trial of an NFTS emulator for Mac, and formatting the USB drive there. I then followed the instructions on [this blog](https://www.top-password.com/blog/create-windows-10-bootable-usb-from-iso-on-mac/). Using Terminal:

1. `diskutil list` to find the name of your USB drive
2. you've already formatted your SB to NTFS so skip step 2
3. `hdiutil mount ~/Downloads/Win10_20H2_v2_English_x64.iso` (iso file name will change with newer versions)
4. `cp -rp /Volumes/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9/* /Volumes/WIN10` (the name of your mounted ISO will change with your version)
5. `hdiutil unmount /Volumes/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9/`

Answer (score 0):

Use netbootin to create the bootable usb! it compresses the install.wim file so it can stand on 4 gb

Comment: It doesn't answer the initial problem.